# opening phpexcel in command prompt

Tags: php, excel-2007, phpexcel

I tried to open my php file in cmd, and this is my error,

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Reader_Exception' with message 'Could
not open NAV USER ACCESS Calculation.xlsx for reading! File does not exist.' in

C:\xampp\htdocs\NAV\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel2007.php:73
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\NAV\PHPExcel\IOFactory.php(269): PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007->c
anRead('NAV USER ACCESS...')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\NAV\PHPExcel\IOFactory.php(191): PHPExcel_IOFactory::createRe
aderForFile('NAV USER ACCESS...')
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\NAV\PHPExcel\updateExcel.php(15): PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('N
AV USER ACCESS...')
#3 {main}
thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\NAV\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel2007.php on line 73
```

Comment: Well it clearly says that the file does not exist, so what is your question? :-)

Comment: Well either the php runtime is not telling the truth or you don't...Make sure the file is accessible to the code which executes it

Answer (score 0):

Try using full path to file you want to open with reader. 
I mean something like this 
`$inputFileName = "C:\File containing your excel file\xlsxName.xlsx";
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);`

Comment: Check out reading privileges of .xlsx file, maybe it has forbidden reading for some group on your device. If your script should be able to read your .xlsx and you're getting this kind of error, double check name of .xlsx file or path to it.